# Preventing the contents of /var/www from being listed when a browser visits my IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ip-address

Heya, how goes it? I have a straight forward ubuntu server running with a bunch of vhosts for multiple subdomains.

But when someone hits http://IP_ADDRESS/ directly, they see the full index of my /var/www/ directory where all the domain files are hosted.

I've searched high and low but can't figure out how to solve this. I know Options -Indexes is the solution but it's not listening to the ones I have in there, namely:

Options -Indexes

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If Options -Indexes isn't working for you remember that it may be overridden somewhere else.  Your Apache uses a variety of configuration files within /etc/apache/conf.d for example as well as its main configuration file.  But as for me, I just put in a blank index.html file (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

What I do is just create a blank file named index.html and put it it /var/www

So simple, but effective.

Comment: easiest solution wins. thanks brotha. any thoughts on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436397/apache-errordocument-after-auth-digest-has-run-and-failed-in-apache2-conf

Answer (score 2):

The default server is the virst vitual server in the list of servers.  It will catch all requests by ip address.  In your case you should restrict the access using allow and deny statements. Access is probabably something like.

```
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Replace the order and allow statements with something like.

```
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
```

You can add additional allow statements for your lan addresses if you like.

Comment: I woulda tried this, but I got somewhat lost. I'm sorry if it's the 'right' solution.. normally I'd tend to promote that, but the other options offered are wayyy easier. I feel like a dick right now :(

Thanks for the thoughts tho!

Comment: @onassar - no reason to be so hard on yourself.  Surely you don't feel like one of those. ;)

Comment: Best security practice is to lock everything down and open up what needs to be open as required.  Don't kick yourself if you didn't do so now.  A lot of experienced people run servers which are fairly wide open.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `Options -Indexes` in the appropriate `VHost` directive or in the `.htaccess` file in /var/www.  You can also just create an index file which the users will get instead of the directory listing.  Finally, you can disable mod_autoindex.

Answer (score 0):

I always put an index.html to my site root as a safety belt. If I later move the site or the settings get modified, the directory listing won't get accidentally revealed. An index.html is a very simple and effective way to stop accidents happening. :-)